# How to check JsonWebToken (JWT) in Headers?

Tags: node.js, jwt, mern, bearer-token

I have a middleware to protect a route. And I am checking whether the token is present in headers or not??

```
if(req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')){
        token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    }
```

***My Question is** is it necessary to add something like already did in above code by adding **Bearer**? is it something that enhance token presence checking or it is just a way.
i think this way should also work

```
if(req.headers.authorization){
        token = req.headers.authorization
    }
```

What will be the difference between these two?

Comment: You can find the difference between the 2 codes by testing. Try sending request: without the header Authorization, with the empty header Authorization, with the header Authorization that doesn't start by 'Bearer', with the header Authorization that starts by 'Bearer' but doesn't contain a space between Bearer and the token ...

Answer (score 0):

> What will be the difference between these two?

```
if(req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')){
        token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    }
```

It will check if the `authorization` header exits and assign the `authorization` string including `bearer` with it and you need to segregate it first to verify the token

```
if(req.headers.authorization){
        token = req.headers.authorization
    }
```

It will check the `authorization` exists or not and if it does, it includes the `Bearer`. It is fine to check, however, not needed unless you follow same approach for all the APIs

You should do this:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');


const verifyToken = async (req, res, next) => {
     const { authorization } = req.headers;
     const token = authorization.split(' ')[1];
     try {
          const jt = await jwt.verify(token, 'key');
          //do something
     } catch (error) {
          res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");
     }
     
}

module.exports = verifyToken;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. The difference between the 2 code.

The 2 codes have the same objective: get the JWT in the header Authorization. They will behave differently based on the way you send the JWT in the request.

#### 2. Explain

Usually, we send the JWT token to the server by using **Bearer Authentication**. In this mode :

> The client must send this token in the Authorization header when
> making requests to protected resources:
>
> Authorization: Bearer [[token]]

(Source : https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/)

So, to retrieve the token from the request, we must :

- Firstly, ensure that the request has the Authorization header in the right format
- Secondly, split the authorization header by space, and the token is the second element of the array.

That is what the first version does.

(*Note*: It should check whether the header contains a space or not before splitting the string

```
if(req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')){
        token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    }
```

)

#### 3. Conclusion

The first version is based on a popular standard and should be use with a small modification :)